Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty r_n=\infty.$
Let $\{D_n\}$ be a sequence of non-overlapping disks with radius $r_n$ contained in a unit disk $D$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. If the Lebesgue measure $m(D\setminus \cup_{n\ge 1} D_n)=0$, then show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty r_n=\infty.$

I read the solution but I do not understand one step in the proof.

Let $I_n$ be the projection of $D_n$ on $x$-axis. Then
$$
\sum_{n\ge 1} |I_n|=2\sum_{n\ge 1}r_n
$$
If not, assume that $\sum_{n\ge 1}r_n<\infty$. Define $x$-section $A_x$ of a subset $A\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ by $A_x:=\{y\in \mathbb{R}: (x,y)\in A\}$.
Then for $x\in [-1,1]$, $x\in I_n$ finitely many (i.e., the section $I_x$ only intersects finitely many $D_n$, say $D_{n(i)}$ for $i=1,\dots, k$.
Since for $x\in [-1,1]$ a.e.,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^km(I_x\cap D_{n_i})<m(I_x\cap D)
$$

I am confused about the above argument... For example, why Then for $x\in [-1,1]$, $x\in I_n$ finitely many? Is it from Borel-Cantell Lemma? How do we get the above display?
I add a picture to explain what is $I_n$:


Let $E=D\setminus \cup_{n\ge 1}D_n$ and $f(x,y)=\chi_E(x,y)$. Then for a.e. $|x|\le 1$, we have $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x,y)dy>0$ and then
$$
m(E)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y)dy)dx>0
$$

So what is the contradiction here?

Does the writeup here help you?

@CalvinLin It looks like the solution is so complicated than mine...

It provides the details of the argument. $\quad$ Since you have not specified what confuses you about the above argument, (EG Do you not understand what "Let $I_n$ be the projection of $D_n$" refers to?) it's hard for anyone to address your confusion. Unfortunately, not all of us are mind readers, so please include more details in the writeup.

You might also want to clarify where the solution is from. Is it from a textbook? Is it from a friend? $\quad$ FWIW I do not understand your writeup (hence I question who it is from). EG 1/ $I_x$ is meaningless to me. It's not defined anywhere. Which interval is associated to the point $ x = 10$? 2/ The projection will likely not intersect $D$, esp if $D$ does not intersect the x-axis. Is there some assumption here? 3/ Is there a leap from the top half and the bottom half? Almost none of the terminology is reflected in the other part. What's going on here?

@CalvinLin Yes, I found this solution from a textbook. (1) Define $x$-section $A_x$ of a subset $A\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ by $A_x:={y\in \mathbb{R}: (x,y)\in A}$. Hope this will be clear?

@CalvinLin I think "the projection of $D_n$" is just the $y$-section of $D_n$?

You've not addressed my points 1, 2, 3 above, so you've not clarified those. $\quad$ Why did you suddenly add in this line? Did you present the entire proof? $\quad$ Edit: Ah, I see that it helps answer 1 by defining $I_x$, which is NOT related to the $I_n$ as projection of $D_n$. So it further confuses the notation because $I_1$ does double duty. So, even though it helps, it hurts too. lol.

@CalvinLin Yes I post whole proof from textbook. I think the projection of a disk on $x$-axis is just the projection... So just image we draw a circle on $R^2$. So the projection is equal to two times its radius... So what the point is confused? If not, I add a picture...
